# Xamarin Forms - Notification Service

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin.forms, service, notifications

I've created a class which is connected with a socket to my Server. I am sending messages from the server to the client. If the client gets the message a notification shows up.

```
public class Chat
{

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private MainPage main;
    private Database db;
    private long lastPong;
    /*
        Packet Syntax 32 bit hash
                       4 bit adressant
                    rest bit nachricht
    */
    public Chat(MainPage main, Database db)
    {
        this.db = db;
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            this.main = main;
            string hash = MainPage.user.hash;
            string to = "0000";
            string msg = "0";
            string packet = hash + to + msg;
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Constant.getServerHost());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint serverAddress = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
            //Connecting
            clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IAsyncResult result = clientSocket.BeginConnect(serverAddress, null, null);
            bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000, true);
            if (clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                main.isMessengerAvailible = true;
                // Sending Login
                byte[] toSendBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(packet);
                byte[] toSendLenBytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(packet.Length);
                clientSocket.Send(toSendLenBytes);
                clientSocket.Send(toSendBytes);
                listen();
                ping();
            }
            else
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    main.ShowMessage("Messenger deaktiviert", "Messenger Modul nicht erreichbar.");
                    main.isMessengerAvailible = false;
                });
            }
        });

    }

    public int sendMessage(String to, String msg)
    {
        string hash = MainPage.user.hash;
        string packet = hash + to + msg;
        if (clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            byte[] toSendBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(packet);
            byte[] toSendLenBytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(packet.Length);
            clientSocket.Send(toSendLenBytes);
            clientSocket.Send(toSendBytes);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    private void ping()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sending Ping");
                sendMessage("0000", "Ping");
                Thread.Sleep(120000);
            }
        });
    }


    public void listen()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                // Receiving
                byte[] rcvLenBytes = new byte[12];
                clientSocket.Receive(rcvLenBytes);
                int rcvLen = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(rcvLenBytes, 0);
                byte[] rcvBytes = new byte[rcvLen];
                clientSocket.Receive(rcvBytes);
                String from = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvBytes, 0, 4);
                String ev = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvBytes, 4, 4);
                String msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvBytes, 8, rcvLen - 8);
                string title = from;
                string message = msg;
                Notification t = new Notification();
                if (from.Equals("0000"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Recived "+ msg);
                    lastPong = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
                }
                else if (from.Equals("0001"))
                {
                    t.Title = "Hello-Perso";
                    t.Message = msg;
                    t.Timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                    db.SaveNotificationAsync(t);
                    main.SendNotificationNow(t);
                }
                else
                {

                    if (!ev.Equals("0000"))
                    {
                        title = ev;
                        message = from + ": " + msg;
                    }

                    Message item = new Message();
                    item.Text = msg;
                    item.FromHash = from;
                    item.EventHash = ev;
                    item.Timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                    db.SaveMessageAsync(item);
                    t.Title = title;
                    t.Message = msg;
                    main.SendNotificationNow(t);
                }
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Now the problem is when i close the app the client disconnect from the server.

I've tried to run the class in a service. But I only managed to create a `ForgroundService` and so there is a Notification all the time the service is running.

But I'm searching for a solution like Whatsapp.  That the app can be closed an I will still get notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances (i.e. not a crash) application termination will happen from the OnSleep state, without any additional notifications to your code.

You could overrde the OnSleep method to reconnect from the server.

```
 public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new Page1();
    }      

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {

     //reconnect to the server

    }
   
}
```

Comment: This is not what i meant. I need to run the Chat Listener independently from the App so the App can be closed an the Listener is still running. I already tried it with a service but the service is also stopped in the App is removed from recent App list .